# How to make PrintStream recognize carriage returns (unicode) in a String?

Tags: string, unicode, ms-word, carriage-return, printstream

I'm essentially trying to use PrintStream to write a single string to a file that contains line breaks, in this case I think it will be a carriage return (CR) '\u000D'. As to where these line breaks will happen is unknown, so I have to format the String itself to do line breaks instead of having PrintStream do it.

Here is where I add the carriage return in the string (which is line):

```
if(useNLTranslator && !isNumber(section))
    line = nlt.translate(line) + System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Here is where I print the string to the text file using PrintStream:

```
try
{
    File file = new File(answer);
    PrintStream print = new PrintStream(file);

    print.println(result);
}
//result is the same as the line string above once its all put together
```

I'm also checking through the String to find where there is a carriage return character and replacing it with something else, the reason for this I won't get into as it would be a very long explanation. I'm using the following to find the carriage return in the String:

```
String cr = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

The problem I'm having is that it is not recognizing the carriage return when searching through the text. This text is taken fairly directly from a Microsoft Word document, which might be part of the issue. Here is what I have that catches when it doesn't recognize the carriage return:

```
//@@DEBUG -- KEEP THIS
String charValue = Character.toString(text.charAt(index));

try{
    current[i] = alphaBits[Character.getNumericValue(text.charAt(index)) - 10][i];
}catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

    //@@DEBUG -- KEEP THIS
    System.out.println("Unrecognized character: " + charValue);
    Character whatIsThis = charValue.charAt(0);
    String name = Character.getName(whatIsThis.charValue());
    System.out.println("Unrecognized character name: " + name);
    System.out.print("You may want to consider adding this character");
    System.out.println(" to the list of recognized characters");

    return "Unrecognized character found.";
}
```

Comment: (1) How are you getting your text from Microsoft Word? (2) are you looking for line breaks or "hard returns"/paragraph marks? Word doesn't mark up line breaks resulting from word wrapping internally, so there would be no detectable character codes in that case in a .doc or .docx (I think).

Comment: 1) I guess I should have said that I actually am taking what's in a Microsoft Word file and converting it to a text file (.txt). 2) I was hoping to catch hard returns and soft returns, I didn't think about soft returns for this though. Is there a way to catch soft returns?

Answer (score 0):

So I actually just figured out the issue I was having. And I guess it would have been hard for anyone to figure this out as I didn't explain what the translate() method did. Oops.

```
if(useNLTranslator && !isNumber(section))
    line = nlt.translate(line) + nlt.translate(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Before I wasn't translating the carriage return / line separator, so it wasn't recognizing it since it was in the wrong format. Thanks for helping me out with this problem though!